# Decoding qr code from image stored on the phone with Zxing (on Android phone)

Tags: java, android, decode, qr-code

I have an app that receives qr code from the server. I want to decode it (not with intent and camera) and display the text it contains in my app.  I have alredy done this in Java SE with jars from zxing with this code:

```
 private class QRCodeDecoder {
         public String decode(File imageFile) {
         BufferedImage image;
         try {
         image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
         } catch (IOException e1) {
         return "io outch";
         }

         // creating luminance source
         LuminanceSource lumSource = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
         BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(lumSource));

         // barcode decoding
         QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();

         Result result = null;
         try {
         result = reader.decode(bitmap);
         } catch (ReaderException e) {
         return "reader error";
         }

         return result.getText();

         }
        }
```

But on Android, BufferedImage is not found. 
Has anyone decoded qr code on android from image stored on the phone?
Tnx.

Comment: Hi!

Did you solve this issue?

I'm having the same problem and until know I was not able to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, i didn't have any luck, so i had to forget this idea. Maybe now, a half year later, things have been solved.

Comment: captureActivity capture QR code image from camera and after decoding it, it shows results according to type of data stored in QR code. e.g. if website URL is encoded in QR code, the result screen will have a button to open that URL and likevise.

I need to read image from SD card, decode it and handle the output in the same manner zxing does in case of decoding via captureActivity.

What do I need to do after getting output in "Result result"?

Comment: @CoolZeroInfinity  any luck ?

Answer (score 21):

In android,you can do it this way:

```
    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            if (bitmap == null)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "uri is not a bitmap," + uri.toString());
                return null;
            }
            int width = bitmap.getWidth(), height = bitmap.getHeight();
            int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
            bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = null;
            RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(width, height, pixels);
            BinaryBitmap bBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
            try
            {
                Result result = reader.decode(bBitmap);
                return result;
            }
            catch (NotFoundException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "decode exception", e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "can not open file" + uri.toString(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: have u tested this solution ?

Comment: can someone please let us know how to get the uri of the image

Answer (score 2):

Download ZXing from google code,  and this class file: `ZXing-1.6/zxing-1.6/androidtest/src/com/google/zxing/client/androidtest/RGBLuminanceSource.java` can help you.

Answer (score -3):

Quickmark and qr droid actually reads out what the code says, and you can decode barcodes saved on your phone. Hit the menu button when your load the image and select share, find decode qr droid or decode quickmark, and the'll do the magic.  I prefer quickmark for reading codes, because it tells me what is typed in the code.