# how to read and decode QR code image from SD card with zxing library?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Zxing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android)

"captureActivity" capture QR code image from camera and after decoding it, it shows results according to type of data stored in QR code. e.g. if website URL is encoded in QR code, the result screen will have a button to open that URL in browser.

I need to read image from SD card, decode it and handle the output in the same manner zxing does in case of decoding via "captureActivity".

I have created a class which extends ListActivity, which browse the SD card images. How can I get the result on onListItemClick event same like it does after capturing image from camera?

Comment: If you just want to decode image via bitmap rather than via camera,you can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422651/decoding-qr-code-from-image-stored-on-the-phone-with-zxing-on-android-phone/14178993#14178993

Comment: please specify the reason for down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android/8708784#8708784). I have given the detailed answer about Zxing QR scanner.