# QR code decoding without using camera in java

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

**     **I am developing a Java Application for reading(decoding) QR Codes with out using camera in the laptop. I am using the ZXING JAR for the generation of QR Code.****

I am doing some manipulation for that QR Code. Now, I wanted to check whether the QR Code is fine or not with out using camera.

Is there any way it can be done?

Comment: If you have access to an image with the QR code, of course you can. If have to scan it from something real, of course you can't without a camera: what's the question actually?

Comment: If i had given a QR Code i.e giving the location of my QR Code image in my system....Is there any way to decode the image....

Comment: Have you read zxing docs? First result for ['ZXing decode qrcode image'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422651/decoding-qr-code-from-image-stored-on-the-phone-with-zxing-on-android-phone) - google is your friend!

Answer (score 2):

ZXing has a [JavaSE module](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/javase) which provides the crucial [`BufferedImageLuminanceSource`](http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/client/j2se/BufferedImageLuminanceSource.html) for decoding a regular Java `BufferedImage`.

The bare minimum, extracted from ZXing's JavaSE [DecodeThread](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/javase/src/com/google/zxing/client/j2se/DecodeThread.java#149):

```
BufferedImage image = ...
LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
```

If `decode()` doesn't throw an exception, ZXing was able to decode the barcode (and you can check the [contents of the bar code](http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/Result.html)).

http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/Reader.html#decode(com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap, java.util.Map)

You can configure the `MultiFormatReader`, e.g. to only parse QR codes, by using the [`decode(BinaryBitmap, Map<DecodeHintType,?> hints)`](http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/Reader.html#decode%28com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap,%20java.util.Map%29) overload, allowing you to specify any number of [decoding hints](http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/DecodeHintType.html). Alternatively, if you really only want QR codes, use a [`QRCodeReader`](http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeReader.html) instead of `MultiFormatReader`.

Comment: Should I include class BufferedImage? 
Because I am getting error to following line
BufferedImage image = .....
"BufferedImage" cannot be resolved type. 
Please, elaborate your response.

Comment: `import` statements are usually implied in code samples, so yes, you'll have to import all classes mentioned in it, including `BufferedImage`.