# Reading QR code in Xamarin Forms With Zxing

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to import a **QR code** from a *.png file* and decode it using [Zxing.Net.Mobile](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile/) and [ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms).

If I scan the QR code using the `ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner` class, the decoding works as required, however, when importing it from a file, the Qr code reader (`ZXing.QrCode.QRCodeReader()`) decode function always returns `null`.

As I'm using **Xamarin Forms**; each platform handles the bitmap/image creation and the portable part handle the rest (`Zxing BinaryBitmap` creation and decoding).

```
//Store rawBytes and image demensions
PotableBitmap bMap = DependencyService.Get<IBitmap>().FileToBitmap(filePath);

RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.RgbBytes, bMap.Width, bMap.Height, RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.RGB32);
HybridBinarizer binarized = new HybridBinarizer(source);
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarized);
var reader = new ZXing.QrCode.QRCodeReader();
data = reader.decode(qrCodeBitmap); // This is always null
```

The `DependencyService` will call the platform specific function, at the moment I am working with Andorid so, the function is as follows:

```
public PortableBitmap FileToBitmap(string ms)
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ms);
    Android.Graphics.Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    int[] intArray = new int[bMap.Width * bMap.Height];
    bMap.GetPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.Width, 0, 0, bMap.Width, bMap.Height)

    List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
    foreach (int intRgb in intArray)
    {
        Color pixelColor = new Color(intRgb);
        result.Add(pixelColor.R);
        result.Add(pixelColor.G);
        result.Add(pixelColor.B);
    }

    return new PortableBitmap(result.ToArray(), bMap.Width, bMap.Height);
}
```

I have looked through some of the posts on SO that are having the same problem and have tried the following:

- Using `BitmapLuminanceSource`: still returns `null` and requires the use of another library
- Using different *bitmap formats* for the `RGBLuminanceSource`: RGB32, BGR32, ARGB32, ABGR32 (each time changing the FileToBitmap function)
- Tried the different `Binarizer`, `GlobalHistogramBinarizer()`
- Checked that the file is being read correctly by reading and wrinting it back to a file.
- I have tried using the `MultiFormatReader()` with the Pure barcode and try harder hints
- I have also debugged the libraries source code and from what I understand it just can't find the QR code in the imported image. No exception is thrown.

Here is where the return `null` is made:

```
private FinderPattern[] selectBestPatterns()
    {
        int startSize = possibleCenters.Count;
        if (startSize < 3)
        {
            // Couldn't find enough finder patterns
            return null; // It returns here
        }
        ...
```

The online [Zxing decoder](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) can decode the QR code I'm testing correctly. Here is my test QR code:

[image: My QR Code Image]

Comment: A java solution to your question, it may help put you on the right path, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422651/decoding-qr-code-from-image-stored-on-the-phone-with-zxing-on-android-phone

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I have already tried this solution without success

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem, with this method in the Android implementation to return an RGBLuminanceSource from the path of the image

```
    public RGBLuminanceSource GetRGBLuminanceSource(string imagePath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(imagePath))
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imagePath);
            List<byte> rgbBytesList = new List<byte>();
            for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
                {
                    var c = new Color(bitmap.GetPixel(x, y));
                    rgbBytesList.AddRange(new[] { c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B });
                }
            }
            byte[] rgbBytes = rgbBytesList.ToArray();
            return new RGBLuminanceSource(rgbBytes, bitmap.Height, bitmap.Width, RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.ARGB32);
        }
        return null;
    }
```