# how can I scan the QR Code that import from my device

Tags: java, qr-code

I have done the import QR Code from my device and insert the QR Code Image to the `ImageView`. But the problem now is how can I scan the QR Code in my `ImageView`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Decoding qr code from image stored on the phone with Zxing (on Android phone)
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422651/decoding-qr-code-from-image-stored-on-the-phone-with-zxing-on-android-phone)